# Xcode archive Stuck compiling Swift source files

Tags: xcode

I am using XCode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002) product. I archive to upload my app to the iTunes Store, which has been stopped for several hours in the 'Compiling Swift source files' section. The actions I have taken to solve this problem are as follows, but have not been resolved.

1. Product> Clean
2. Product> Clean Build Folder
3. OS reboot
4. Sign out and sign in
5. Even up to hardware memory upgrades

The biggest question is that the test runs well on all devices. However, when I try to archive, it stops at that section without any error message.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning out Derived Data?

Comment: @ILikeTau is that a Product->Cleaning?

Comment: Nope. There's a folder in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` that should correspond to your project; delete it.

Comment: @ILikeTau Thanks for comment but, I already I deleted all of files in DerivedData but nothing change.

Comment: Could you try making a trivial change and compiling again?

Comment: @ILikeTau I am sorry, but please tell me for a detailed explanation or link to refer to it.

Comment: At this point I really don't have any idea what is going on, and there's not much I can do without more information. Do you mind providing some of the code or maybe a couple screenshots?

Comment: @ILikeTau Thank you for your reply. But I solved the problem.
1. Reduced image file size. I upgraded the memory of the hardware from 4GB to 10GB. 3. Press and hold the archive button to sleep. 4. When I woke up, it was miraculously complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miraculously I solved this problem.
1. Reduced image file size.
I upgraded the memory of the hardware from 4GB to 10GB.
3. Press and hold the archive button to sleep.
4. When I woke up, it was miraculously complete.

The image file was 40MB, but it was reduced to 20MB. And I upgraded my MacBook memory in the hardware from 4GB to 10GB, but I do not know which one helped me solve the problem. Anyway, I have solved this problem and hope you can help if you have difficulties with the same problem.